# Mobile Broadband wizard on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

Is there such a thing as a Mobile Broadband wizard in Raspbian, something similar to the interface you use in others linux distributions GUI like Ubuntu, to set a new network device. Where you are only ask to select a carrier and input the APN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Raspberry Pi is not mainly meant to be a mobile device. So its default operating system **Raspbian** does not support this out of the box. You can try to install **NetworkManager** but that isn't supported by Raspbian so it may have problems to integrate into the GUI. You can find some Q&A here on this site about this but with very low support. So I'm afraid you are alone with this setup.

I'm not familiar with **Ubuntu** but as far as I know it is using NetworkManager, also on a Raspberry Pi. You can try to use Ubuntu instead of Raspbian.